# Intent resolution in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, conflict

If I want to create custom address book (which overrides my phone's default address book), and if I want it to be used by **all** applications, what should be my `intent-filter`? Does Android allow me to do such a thing considering the fact that such a third-party app could potentially be malicious?!

And, if I want to have yet another address book application, I suppose the second app also has same `intent-filter`, isn't it? How does the framework decide which app to pick if I click on Contacts button when making a call? In other words, how does the framework resolve intents in case,there is a conflict between multiple `intent-filters`?

Answer (score 3):

You can replace any application on Android platform, even Home. Android documentation explains everything there is to know about [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) and there is a section called [Intent Resolution](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ires) that answers your question. Intent Resolution section for [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)  class has some additional information.

As far as I can tell Android doesn't try to resolve a conflict. It ask the user which application to run and gives them the choice to mark this Activity as the default for this Intent. They give an example about mail app [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER).

Comment: Hi Nikola,


Thanks for your reply. I have read the documentation on android developers' portal. However, the answer to my question still eludes me...


From what I understood, if an activity/application advertises that it supports certain intent using appropriate intent-filters, then the framework can route intent to that activity easily. However, my question is: if there are two applications with exactly same intent filter, how does the framework pick one? Don't say by rolling a dice . :)


Saksham

Comment: Nikola is right. Android asks a user to decide which app to use. For example, if there is an address link, I would see a dialog on my Evo to choose between Google Maps and Sprint Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

While Mr. Smiljanić is basically correct, there is no Contacts application in Android for you to replace. There is Dialtacts, which is the application supporting the contacts, call log, and dialer. That application cannot be replaced, mostly because the dialer cannot be replaced.

So, while you may be able to override some intent filters and get control on some contacts-related requests, you will be unable to get the contacts portion of Dialtacts overridden, which will confuse users.

Comment: HTC have made their custom address book with the Sense UI, and one of the things I've read online (which I might have misunderstood) is that you can customize pretty much everything on Android using appropriate intents/intent-filters. Question is, can I override the address book in, for instance, HTC hero? If I can, then what if I have address book apps A and B; which one will the framework pick?

Many thanks

Comment: "that you can customize pretty much everything on Android using appropriate intents/intent-filters" -- on the whole, yes. However, "pretty much everything" != "everything". You cannot replace Dialtacts on a Hero.